# Error Al ejecutar Laravel descargado de Git, warning bootstrap

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, git

Saludos, he descargado un proyecto de Laravel de un repositorio el cual soy colaborador y a la hora de ejecutarlo (previamente lo metí en htdocs y cambié en Netbeans la ruta de ejecucción) sale el siguiente error :

```
Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\Aspace\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aspace\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Aspace\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aspace\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
```

Mi compañero dice que ha subido el proyecto entero a Git.

El caso es que la semana pasado YO hice exactamente lo mismo, subí un proyecto entero, y les dije a mis compis que lo descargaran , y cuando lo ejecutaron le salió el mismo error.

***Solución:::***

```
El problema estaba en que al descargar el proyecto le faltaba el archivo .env, después de que me lo pasaran por pendrive funcionó todo.
```

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta en StackOverflow en inglés es muy similar y podría ayudarte a solucionar el problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468625/laravel-5-failed-opening-required-bootstrap-vendor-autoload-php

Comment: Gracias comentaré por allí, pero de momento haciendo eso no funciona

Comment: No me deja, necesito 50 de reputación y me da error:

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

ya corriste el comando:

```
composer install
```

Si te ocurre al ejecutar el comando podrias probar modificando en el archivo composer.json la llave scripts los valores de "pre-update-cmd" y "post-update-cmd":

```
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [

    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [

    ]
},
```

y volver a intentar composer install, si te funciona lo vuelves a dejar como estaba y ya debería funcionar bien. Saludos

Comment: El composer ya lo tenía instalado para poder hacer ejercicios de Laravel.Usé el composer update --no-scripts dentro de la carpeta del proyecto y dejó de salir el error del bootstrap/autoload.php y ahora simplemente sale el "  Whoops, looks like something went wrong " Si me pasan el proyecto en un pendrive, no hay problema, pero al descargar de git, no podemos ejecutarlo nadie.